# Why are the formula's of negative entropy and computational complexity so close?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, information-theory

The negative entropy for a vector $n$ with k dimensions is $ \Sigma_{k} nlogn$  defined as 0 for $n = 0$. Similarly the computational complexity for algorithms which repeatedly divide an input of size $n$ by a constant is $\mathcal{O}(n\log{}n)$. What is the relation or is it a coincidence ?

Comment: What is the negative entropy of a function (how is it defined)?

Comment: Thanks. I think it's fine now ?

Comment: I hate to say it,  but I cannot make sense of that definition.  Where did you encounter that?

Comment: I got it from the Boyd and Vandenberghe textbook. You can also find it on the wiki page on Entropy under 'Definition'.

Comment: I know what entropy is, and it is **not** what you wrote. First, the "function" $f$ plays not role in your definition. Second, entropy as the "logarithmic measure of the number of states with significant probability of being occupied" (cf. the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy#Definitions_and_descriptions) you mention) deals with probability distributions over $n$ states, not with arbitrary functions. Third, it is of the form $-\sum_{k=1}^n p(k)\log p(k)$, not "$-\sum_{k=1}^n n\log n$" (which, again, would not even feature the probability distribution $p$!).

Comment: And then, the entropy (there is no "negative" entropy. That's just the entropy) is maximized for a uniform distribution $p=u_n$, for which is takes value $H(u_n)=\log n$ -- not $n\log n$. So, to answer your question: there is no direct connection, and further your definition of entropy is incorrect...

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing that. Looks like I was confused.

Comment: You're welcome.